# Why function count() make an error with gorup by?

Tags: mysql, sql

i was test a query for make database name with random number in value that stored in column in some table . and its works .

the query :

```
mysql> select 1,concat( ( select database() ),floor(rand(0)*2) )a from users group by a ;
```

result:

```
+---+-----------+
| 1 | a         |
+---+-----------+
| 1 | security0 |
| 1 | security1 |
+---+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

database tabel :

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | username   | password   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | Dumb       | Dumb       |
|  2 | Angelina   | I-kill-you |
|  3 | Dummy      | p@ssword   |
|  4 | secure     | crappy     |
|  5 | stupid     | stupidity  |
|  6 | superman   | genious    |
|  7 | batman     | mob!le     |
|  8 | admin      | admin      |
|  9 | admin1     | admin1     |
| 10 | admin2     | admin2     |
| 11 | admin3     | admin3     |
| 12 | dhakkan    | dumbo      |
| 13 | admin11    | password11 |
| 14 | admin4     | admin4     |
| 15 | admin_test | NULL       |
| 16 | admin      | NULL       |
+----+------------+------------+
```

but when i put function count() in the query its give me this error:

```
mysql> select count(*),concat( ( select database() ),floor(rand(0)*2) )a from users group by a ;
```

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'security1' for key ''

so why function count() make this error ?

Comment: This error does not relate to the `SELECT` query (as demonstrated below by Gordon Linoff). It likely comes from an `insert` or `update`. Also, can you show us your expected result?

Comment: @GMB , as i said above i just want put database name and random number in one column , but as extra knowledge i put count(),max(), and they give me an error , so why is that ?

Comment: It is unclear to me why you want to use aggregate funtion for... Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58574732/edit) to show us the result that you expect, as tabular text?

Comment: @GMB , to make it clear for you sir , why when i put an aggregate funtion with group by , its show me an duplicate error ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you are asking about:

```
select count(*),
       concat( ( select database() ), floor(rand(0)*2) ) as a
from users
group by a
```

works when I try it in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d244ffecc2a6b9210cea6a32ae9b94e).  I would point out that the subquery is unnecessary, so the equivalent is:

```
select count(*),
       concat( database(), floor(rand(0)*2) ) as a
from users
group by a
```

Comment: thanks , but i just wanna know why when i use count(), this give me an error ? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: `count()` requires an argument.

Comment: i put count(*) , or count(1) , its not the error , the error said duplicate .

Comment: Do you have any column as primary key made?

Comment: @Learn005 . . . That particular error should only be happening on an `insert` (or possibly an `update`).  To get a duplicate key error, you need to be modifying the data.

Comment: Exactly @Gordon the OP got this error on insert probably

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct although The error you have got is on inserting the data as `concat( (  select database() ),floor(rand(0)*2) )a` this is giving duplicates as security1 multiple times

```
   select distinct count(*),concat( ( 
   database() ),floor(rand(0)*2) )a from 
    users group by a
```

Comment: ooh thanks ! , but you mean the reason for Error is database() variable will repeat it self multiple times in group by column ?

Comment: Not the database but the random value may be same at times (maybe on rerunning the query as well) so as the error above you got random no as 1 again with same database name hence the combination made is duplicate